# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

Total newbie here: I keep getting this error message and I have no idea why. The attached pic shows just a simple example. I imagine it might be something simple, maybe there is a property I need to adjust but I just can't fix it. Does anyone have any idea?

[Bash:syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SNEz.png)

Comment: When do you get that message? The screenshot indicates you typed the `&`. So, why?

Comment: Also, in general you should copy the command and error in text and add it to the question, instead of an image

Comment: No idea. I tried the answers below but it didn't work either.
A colleague suggested that I check the settings on VS for terminal and we tried to put the same settings as he had and now it works fine.

Thanks for the tip, WurmD. Will do it from now on!

Answer (score 0):

try executing `python test.py`(file name) in terminal where the file is located

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're executing this command:

```sh
$ & c:/Users/(username)/path/to/Activate.ps1
```

And you get a syntax error for the `&`. So to run that file, your command should not have that `&`.

Tip: when executing a command from a file like that, you can use a path relative to your terminal path (I don't know if I'm describing it right but in your case its `~/Documents/my_dev/test`).

So, your new command should look like this:

```sh
$ .\venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

Note: not a windows user, I used [this article](https://camerondwyer.com/2014/10/30/what-are-ps1-files-and-how-you-use-them/) for reference